# I have failed endlessly trying to write the code in VBA to insert this formula into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

**The formula:**

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(E10=0,D9=0),0,NETWORKDAYS(D9,E9))," ")
```

**An example of what I've tried in VBA:**

```
Sub inputWorkdays()

Range("h9").Formula =  "=IFERROR(IF(OR(E9=0,D9=0),0,NETWORKDAYS(D9,E9)),""Yes"")"


 End Sub
```

I'm trying to add the formula from above into cell H9.

Comment: What version of excel are you using? That inserted for me, using Excel 2007

Comment: Does an error appear when you try to run this code? If so what does the error say?

Comment: In the first case you have `(E10=0,D9=0)` and in the second `(E9=0,D9=0)`.  (`E10` changed to `E9`). Is that it??

Comment: Latest version. Ignor the E10 etc, sorry. I copied the formula from the cell under, bc I have E9 blank but didn't rewrite it properly for this forum.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. As I have this code written in but nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe try using single quotes to wrap the formula? '=IFERROR(IF(OR(E9=0,D9=0),0,NETWORKDAYS(D9,E9)),""Yes"")'

Comment: Perhaps specify which `Worksheet` you are using, e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("H9").Formula = ...`

Comment: Am I the only one that does not realize why you do not follow my answer and see the formula yourself? Two formulas would be printed, choose one of them. ============v

Comment: He's trying to put the formula into a cell, not extract it...

Comment: I think everyone was helpful. I would like to close this question if that is the next step. I'm just going to figure out how to loop this. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cell with the formula and write the following:

```
Sub TestMe
   debug.print Selection.Formula
   debug.print Selection.FormulaR1C1
End sub
```

In your case it would give:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(E10=0,D9=0),0,NETWORKDAYS(D9,E9)),"YES")
=IFERROR(IF(OR(R[-4]C[-1]=0,R[-5]C[-2]=0),0,NETWORKDAYS(R[-5]C[-2],R[-5]C[-1])),"YES")
```

Take the first one and use it like this:

```
Range("h9").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR(E10=0,D9=0),0,NETWORKDAYS(D9,E9)),""YES"")"
```

Comment: @Jordan, thank you for the edition. Usually I am using my method, but I do not write strings in my formulas often, thus I am not that used to it.

Comment: everyone please be patient. You all are amazing thank you. Let me try all this.

Answer (score 1):

I gather from the comments that there is no error, just "nothing happens". I see nothing wrong with your code. Except...

> ```
> Range("h9").Formula = "..."
> ```

When `Range` is *unqualified* like this, you implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`; if the active sheet isn't the sheet you're expecting to write to, then it's easy to conclude that "nothing happens" and that the code doesn't work.

If you have [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) installed (full disclosure: I'm heavily involved with the development of this open-source VBE add-in), you will see that `Range` in this case is a member of `Excel._Global`, and an inspection result will tell you that you're implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`:

[image: Excel._Global.Range implicitly refers to ActiveSheet]

```
Range("H9").Formula = "..."
```

> *Implicit references to the active sheet make the code frail and harder to debug. Consider making these references explicit when they're intended, and prefer working off object references.*
>
> <sub>http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReferenceInspection</sub>

To fix this, qualify the `Range` call with a `Worksheet` object - now the `Range` call is a member of the `Excel.Worksheet` class:

[image: Excel.Worksheet.Range is qualified]

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

sheet.Range("H9") = "..."
```

By qualifying `Range` calls with a worksheet object, you make sure that you're always writing to the worksheet you mean to write to - not the worksheet that happens to be the active one when the code runs.

Comment: something here is working. thank you. I got a "yes" returned. I'll figure out now how to make it work. thank you and to everyone else too